# How to get current ID record in a domain field in OpenERP7?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Simple OpenERP7 question:

I adding a new field to a model. This field is a many2one. It is going to show every active partner which has a specific parent_id: this parent_id must be the ID of the current record. How can I do this?

Here, one of my failed attempts. It should be something like this:

```
'main_contact_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Main Contact', domain=[('active','=',True), ('parent_id','=',self.id)]),
```

Comment: try self.ids somehow maybe it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!!

This is the way to manage this:

```
<field
      name="main_contact_id"
      domain="[('parent_id','=',context.get('active_id', False))]"
/>
```

or

```
<field
      name="main_contact_id"
      domain="[('parent_id','=',active_id)]"
/>
```

Comment: I believe you can just use `[('parent_id', '=', active_id)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the model definition as there is no concept of the ID of the current record (this is the model definition after all, not an instance of a record).  You should add this domain on the field in the form and you should be able to use ID from memory.  Domains in a model can only use static information such as your active = True.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But from the XML view, how do I get the current id? For example, <field name="main_contact_id" domain="[('parent_id', '=', 5)]" />, is working as I want, because 5 is the ID of the current record. How can I turn that 5 into a variable?